# Having trouble with [username].github.io

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I was recently introduced to the wonder of hosting free gh-pages on github. I was able to create a few gh-pages branches for repos on my github account and had no trouble sharing and distributing links like "my_username.github.io/my_repo" and "my_username.github.io/my_other_repo". Then I learned that I could make a nice landing page by creating a repo called "my_username.github.io". All of the links worked perfectly.

I started to run into trouble when I wanted to set up a custom domain for my_username.github.io. I purchased "my_domain.com" and followed all of the instructions  [here](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages). When I visit "my_domain.com", I see the content from "my_username.github.io" .... Nice! However, when I visit "my_domain.com/my_repo", I get the github 404 page saying "there isn't a github page here". When I visit "my_username.github.io/my_repo", it redirects to "my_domain.com/my_repo" and displays the same 404 page. At [namecheap.com](http://www.namecheap.com/) (where I purchased the "my_domain.com"), I have:

```
@   204.232.175.78           A (address) 
www my_username.github.io    CNAME (alias)
```

Then in the root of the repo "my_username.github.io" I have a file called CNAME that only contains the text "my_domain.com".

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong as this setup seems to work as intended for others.  One possible culprit is that my github username is in CapitalizedCamelCase.

Anyway, I was wondering if anyone else had worked through a similar issue and had some advice. If it helps, here is a link to the actual repo in question:

https://github.com/ScottLNorvell/ScottLNorvell.github.io

Thanks!

Comment: Web hosting with a web app makes this is better for either [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) or [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) (and since it's not dealing with how to use Git), or direct to GitHub:Support

Comment: It should still work. Can you give me an example of one that doesn't redirect properly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Now that you have a custom domain, your project pages are available at `yourcustomdomain.com/project_page`.

When you setup a GH Pages site for `username.github.io` and use a custom domain, you can no longer access project pages from `username.github.io/project_page`, but you can access them from `yourcustomdomain.com/project_page` directly. While there is a redirect in place for `username.github.io => yourcustomdomain.com`, there is no redirect for  `username.github.io/project_page => yourcustomdomain.com/project_page` so you should point all links/traffic for your project pages directly to `yourcustomdomain.com/project_page`.

More info on custom domains for GitHub Pages and automatic redirects here: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages#automatic-redirects

Also, please note that you should not be using both a CNAME and A record from your DNS provider, only the A record. You should remove the CNAME record from your DNS providers settings because that is handled on GitHubs servers via the [CNAME file](https://github.com/ScottLNorvell/ScottLNorvell.github.io/blob/master/CNAME) you have in the root of your pages repo.

*NOTE: I work at GitHub. Let me know if you still have trouble.*

Comment: Thanks @Joel! I contacted GitHub directly per @mgarciaisaia 's suggestion. They were able to rebuild the pages for me and now they work. I think it was a bug. The rebuild gets triggered every time you push to the page, so a suggestion to others that have this problem would be to re-push to the gh-pages of projects that aren't working.

Comment: Awesome - glad you got it sorted out Scott!

Comment: Is there a way to host the repo of the root domain on the gh-pages branch and still have other project repos work properly? I have rootdomain.com on gh-pages with a CNAME file, however all the other project repos are broken.

Comment: @cameronjroe I'm not sure I follow your scenario, but you can email GitHub support for help with that. There is a support form at https://github.com/contact. Be sure to give as much details and explanation as possible, including the actual repos/pages affected.

Comment: @JoelGlovier I simply reversed my build to have my `src` directory in a source branch and have it build to `master`. It's working fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a real cause to your problem. Try [contacting GitHub support](https://github.com/contact) to see if they can help - they're really nice people and answer pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem is that I place `CNAME` file outside of the `source` folder in the `source` branch, so that `rake generate` does not work

Now place `CNAME` into `source` folder in the `source` branch, then `rake generate` and `rake deploy` will make that `CNAME` into the root folder in the `master` branch